# Copy lines in a file and paste it into a new file

Tags: clipboard

I have 12 files each containing 10 lines.

I need to copy the content of the first file to a new file (new.txt)
Then I need to copy the lines 6 to the end (10) of the 11 remaining files in the same new.txt

Anybody knows any tips to do that?

Regards,
Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat 1.txt > new.txt
for f in 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt 10.txt 11.txt 12.txt; do tail -5 $f >> new.txt; done
```

This copies the contents of the first file to new.txt.
Then the `for` extracts the last 5 lines (6 to 10) of your files (excluding the first file) and appends to new.txt
If the file names following a certain pattern, you don't need to list all of them by name in the `for`, but use e.g. *.txt. But the pattern would also need to exclude the first file and new.txt.

Comment: Dear williamvoor, thanks for the suggestion but it gives: tail: cannot open `$f' for reading: No such file or directory.

Comment: @Serge Can you paste here the exact `for` line you used?.

Comment: It is working, thanks. The error occured when I tried to run the script in .bat file (I'm on Windows using cygwin) and other linux functionalities. When I type directly in Cygwin, it was fine. On the other hand, I also made another script for it using `cat 1.asc > new.asc foreach n (2 3 4 5) sed -n '7,200p' $n.asc | cat >> new.asc end ` that I could run as .bat file.